# Problem with React Deployment to Github Pages

Tags: reactjs, deployment, github-pages

I am doing exactly like in this instruction https://create-react-app.dev/docs/deployment/#github-pages-https-pagesgithubcom

But still can't see my project on this url https://vladislav747.github.io/ReactChat/

Code here https://github.com/Vladislav747/ReactChat

Can't understand what am i doing wrong?

I am thinking about these issues of problem(See it in Terminal)

```
The project was built assuming it is hosted at /.
You can control this with the homepage field in your package.json.
```

Because of these lines - i think that it is hosted not on root route.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you've a typo in your package.json

> homepaage